# Find all elements of arraylist

Tags: vba, arraylist

Is there any way to find all elements that interest me in the arraylist?

lets say the values are

```
arr.add("mark")
arr.add("john")
arr.add("eli")
arr.add("mark")
arr.add("peter")
```

And I want to find indexes of the "johns".

```
arr.contains
```

will return me true or false value
and

```
arr.indexof("")
```

will return index of the FIRST found value

Comment: You could use LINQ select I think...

Comment: You should try to use a `List(Of String)` instead of an `ArrayList` whenever you can

Comment: @MattWilko List<T> appeard in .net 2.0 so I cant use it in vba

Comment: If this is VBA, then why is it tagged VB.NET?

Comment: @MattWilko sorry for the oversight then ;) still appreciate your input it opened my eyes somehow for new stuff

Comment: @Ian yup, I posted my answer, unfortunately List(Of T) doesn't exist in VBA (vb.net is another thing, on newer framework)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem quite easily:

```
Function duplSearch(val As String, arrayList As Object, i As Long) As Object

Dim temp As Long
Dim results As Object

Set results = CreateObject("System.Collections.Arraylist")

    For i = i + 1 To arrayList.Count
        If arrayList.indexof(val, i) = -1 Then
            i = arrayList.Count
        Else
            temp = arrayList.indexof(val, i)
            results.Add (temp)
            i = temp + 1
        End If
    Next i
    Set duplSearch = results.Clone

    End Function
```

Comment: NB, if you just want the index of val in the entire list, and don't care about the starting point then use `arrayList.indexOf_3(val)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 Dim arr As New ArrayList
 arr.Add("mark")
 arr.add("john")
 arr.add("eli")
 arr.add("mark")
 arr.Add("peter")
 arr.Add("john")


Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To arr.ToArray.Count - 1
    If arr(i) = "john" Then
      Console.WriteLine("Index Of John :" & i)
    End If
Next
```

Result:

```
Index Of John : 1
Index Of John : 5
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `System.Collections.ArrayList`, you are able to use `.IndexOf` as well. Just do not forget to write `,0` as a second parameter. Thus this works quite well:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim testList As Object
    Set testList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    testList.Add "mark"
    testList.Add "john"
    testList.Add "eli-saveta"
    testList.Add "peter the keeper with nothing to do"

    Debug.Print testList.IndexOf("john", 0)

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

to find e item in arraylist you can use `indexOf(item, start_index)`

```
    Set myAL = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    myAL.Add ("the")
    myAL.Add ("quick")
    myAL.Add ("brown")
    myAL.Add ("fox")
    myAL.Add ("jumps")
    myAL.Add ("over")
    myAL.Add ("the")
    myAL.Add ("lazy")
    myAL.Add ("dog")
    myAL.Add ("in")
    myAL.Add ("the")
    myAL.Add ("barn")

    Dim myIndex As Integer
    myIndex = myAL.IndexOf("the", 0)  'return 0
    myIndex = myAL.IndexOf("the", 1)  'return 6
    myIndex = myAL.IndexOf("the", 7)  'return 10
```